# Making general Filter in Djando Rest Framework

Tags: django, filter, django-rest-framework, django-filters

I want to make a common filter to my models because I need to filter all my objects to return a gap between time_start and time_end, but apparently it doesn't work.
I'm not sure if it's even possible(But I hope so, because it won't by DRY otherwise).

**models.py**

```
class Time(models.Model):
    time = models.TimeField()
    class Meta:
        abstract=True


class Mark(Time):
    value = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="mark")
    teacher = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class MarkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Mark
        fields = ('id', 'time','value', 'teacher', 'subject')
```

**filers.py**

```
class DataFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    start_time = django_filters.TimeFilter(name="time", lookup_expr='gte')
    end_time = django_filters.TimeFilter(name="time", lookup_expr='lte')

    class Meta:
        model = Time
        fields = ['start_time', 'end_time']
```

**views.py**

```
class MarkViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = MarkSerializer
    queryset = Mark.objects.all()
    filter_class = DataFilter
```

I try to get needed marks through: 
***127.0.0.1:8000/api/v0/marks/?time_start=11:40:00&time_end=12:00:00***
but it returns all the objects that I have not the filtered ones.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have passed the filter params wrong, it should be the name of the field you described in the filter class `DataFilter`.

Hit this endpoint in the browser,
`127.0.0.1:8000/api/v0/marks/?start_time=11:40:00&end_time=12:00:00`